# RStudio: Finding mean, median, st. dev., min, and max for dummy variables

Tags: excel, rstudio

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oLPD.png)

I saved my Excel worksheet as a tab delimited text file. I'm trying to use RStudio to find the statistics for (Y)GPA, mentioned in the title, for each dummy variable: first, middle, and last.

Comment: Just using `summary` on the various columns might be enough to meet your needs.  Have you written code yet to read in the file?  Your question is a bit broad.

Comment: Yes, I've used read.table to read my file. I'm not sure how to use summary with dummy variables. I end up getting the statistics for all the 1's and 0's instead of the GPA mean, median, st. dev, min, and max for First, Middle, and Last.

Comment: You should show an example of the kind of data you've got.  There are several ways to code "dummy variables" in R; knowing which one you used would help.  (But be aware that those statistics don't make sense for all of them...)

Comment: Assuming your data frame is called `df`, use `summary(df$GPA)` for example.

Comment: I linked my data. I'm not allowed to post a direct photo since I'm a new member.

Comment: I understand that's how I would find the total GPA summary statistics, but I am trying to find the mean, median, etc. for each of my dummy variables: first, middle, and last.